How to handle globalOffSet changing in forge viewer
Following the below post I'm facing the same problem as the globalOffSet may change once the model changes.
Forge viewer globaloffset change breaks moving in and select
Forge uses this globalOffSet value in order to set the view points, the problem is that if this values changes, the resulted view points will also change.
Does anyone know how to handle this ?

The global offset should be independent from any custom views. As the original Stack Overflow answer says, the offset is mainly used to bring models that are far from the origin close to (0,0,0) to avoid floating point precision issues (and yes, if the model changes, the global offset may change as well) but this should not have any impact on the custom views.
